# angular 10 changes not getting reflected when deployed in iis?

Tags: angular, visual-studio, iis

Any time, I make code changes in .hmtl file or the .js file, the browser still renders the old code and my new code changes don't show up in the browser result.

```
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="dashboard-stat blue-madison">
      <div class="details">
        <div class="desc">
          {{this.satations.stationName}}
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="more" href="#/signals">
        View more <i class="m-icon-swapright m-icon-white"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then I do the following:

```
In VS2019, right click on my project and view in browser (IE or Chrome).
Login to my application.
Go the respective page and I see the rendering of the old html file. I do not see the newly added 2 div elements rendered at all.
```

What am I doing wrong?

I even hit f5 to refresh the browser but still no luck.
I also cleared the cache of google chrome and IIS it worked for once and again the changes are not reflecting and i tried the answers in the stack overflow but there is no result and thanks in advance for the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had to rebuild the project every time the changes were made this not permanent solution but a walk around

Answer (score 0):

After you deploy your project, you will find that there will be an extra PublishProfiles folder in Visual Studio. The content of this folder is the configuration file for publishing program information. You can try to delete this folder, and then run your project.

Comment: how to delete the folder ??

Comment: You can delete the folder in the visual studio.